# Why wont this program give me the sum of two variables

Tags: if-statement, sum, addition

> Im very new to coding. I have been tasked with creating a program that will allow the user to input two int variables and then use a What If statement to give me the sum of the two variables. But when I run the program, I keep getting "0" as the sum.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhatIf {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard  = new Scanner(System.in);
    int firstNumber = 0 , secondNumber = 0 ;
    int sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;

        System.out.println("Enter First Number: " );
        firstNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Second Number ");
        secondNumber = keyboard.nextInt();



        System.out.println("Sum of the two numbers is: " + sum);
    }

}
```

Comment: `int sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;` doesn't set the value of sum as a function of `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` - it computes the value immediately. When you initialize `sum`, both `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` are 0, so 0+0=0. Move the statement to after you read the ints in.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the programming world.

Here in the code, you are doing the sum first and then taking the input from the user, which won't be considered.

You should change 1 line of code here. Try it, and if unsuccessful let me know, I will give the code.